# Align SVG text centrally on one line

Tags: svg

I'm having my first go at a donut chart using SVG.

I've made the chart and am now trying to put text dead center in the ring.

I've managed to achieve this using a simple text element using a single style, however, I'd like to style the suffix differently. In order to do so I've created 2 spans.

```css
.donut-wrapper {
max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="donut-wrapper">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
      <circle class='donut-ring' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#e0e0e0' stroke-width='4'></circle><circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#00c853' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25'></circle>
      <text x="50%" class="chart-label">
         <tspan y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" class="number">99</tspan><tspan y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" class="suffix">%</tspan>
     </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

As you will see, I've managed to align the text vertically but have been unable to center the text horizontally.

Also, I would like the '%' suffix to be half the size of the 'number' and align with the top of the number.

I've read lots of articles on aligning multi line text but can't find what I need for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need text-anchor="middle". Note that Firefox does not support alignment-baseline but it does support dominant-baseline.

There does seem to be a cross-browser rendering issue with the y attribute and the multiple tspan elements you have. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to fix that in a cross-browser manner.

```css
.donut-wrapper {
max-width: 200px;
}

.suffix {
font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="donut-wrapper">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
      <circle class='donut-ring' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#e0e0e0' stroke-width='4'></circle><circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#00c853' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25'></circle>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
         <tspan class="number">99</tspan><tspan dy="-0.25em" class="suffix">%</tspan>
     </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice Robert and the tip regarding cross browser compatibility.

Comment: For other searchers information, Firefox slightly mis-aligns the suffix. MS Edge, on the other hand, fails to vertically align anything.

Comment: @JohnOhara I've fixed the Firefox alignment (my fault) and also display the % half size and aligned with the top of the numbers. This version seems to work in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use some script you can place text as you desire

```js
var svgText  = document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0];
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0];
var suffix = document.getElementsByClassName("suffix")[0];


var bbox = svgText.getBBox();

svgText.setAttribute("x", bbox.x-bbox.width/2); 
svgText.setAttribute("y", bbox.y+bbox.height); 
suffix.setAttribute("y", bbox.y+bbox.height*.75); 

console.log(bbox);
```

```css
.donut-wrapper {
max-width: 200px;
}

.number{
  font-size:1em;
}
.suffix{
  font-size:.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="donut-wrapper">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
      <circle class='donut-ring' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#e0e0e0' stroke-width='4'></circle><circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#00c853' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25'></circle>
      <text x="50%" y="50%">
         <tspan class="number">99</tspan>
         <tspan class="suffix">%</tspan>
     </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

(maybe you have to reajust for IE as `getBBox()` doesn't return the same height and width on IE)